# Custom role command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need help with custom_role command. It should create for user role with custom name and colour.

For now i have only:

```
@Bot.command()
async def custom_role(ctx):
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name = "role")

    emb = discord.Embed(description = "Role created!", color = 0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code?

Comment: What's the error? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't have any error, I just want to make command that can create custom role for a user, this role should have custom name and colour

Comment: @selion woudn't it be better to have a set of colour roles and let users choose from those colours? This would just keep making more and more roles. Personally I think that's a bad idea.

Comment: No, I want to add this command to economy bot, so tt won't keep making more roles, I also forgot, that I want this command to create temp custom roles, but this isn't problem, I only don't know how to make command that can create custom roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you can pass the role name and colour as parameters and create a custom role with those specified as so:

```
@Bot.command()
async def custom_role(ctx, colour: str, *, name: str):
    colour = discord.Color(value=int(colour, 16))
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name = name, colour=colour)

    emb = discord.Embed(description = "Role created!", color = 0x2ecc71)
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
```

Example of usage (assuming the prefix is '!'):

```
!custom_role 0xa83232 test role # Creates a role named 'test role' in the color red
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. I tried to use " :str" but I was doing this wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```py
@Bot.command()
async def custom_role(ctx):
    permissions = discord.Permissions()
    await ctx.guild.create_role(name = 'role', colour = discord.Colour(0x2ecc71), permissions = permissions)
```

Learn more about permissions [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#permissions).